# problem during GSN installation

Tags: server, mysql

grant usage on *.* to gsn@localhost identified by ‘gsnpassword’; is this a correct syntax for  user 'gsn' to connect to the server from localhost using the password 'gsnpassword':in Mysql Server version 5.5.47.0ubuntu0.14.04.1?

When I am using this "grant usage on *.* to gsn@localhost identified by ‘gsnpassword’;"  I am getting a error- ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '‘gsnpassword’' at line 1.
plz help me to solve this problem

Vishnupriya

Comment: Why this question is asked in this forum? Be very specific and clear

Answer (score 0):

You should be referring to this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) to verify your mysql grant permission syntax. Do refer to the right version of MySQL. And please make sure to google first and post the questions in the right forum.